# Errors in null element condition "if" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

I know it doesn't exist it's going to exist later.

There's a JSON box that opens up a text area. The element `text_area` is not present until that button is pressed. I want to `check_for_element()` until the element exists. I already had a solution below that works with `setInterval`. I don't know why my `if` statement keeps throwing errors. How can I get no errors when testing if element exists or doesn't exists?

```
//I tried if (type of ), var text_area = document.query...

$( document ).ready(function() {


    function check_for_element() {


    if ( ! document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized")[1]){

        console.log("searching for element.....");
        window.requestAnimationFrame(check_for_element );
    }

    }


window.requestAnimationFrame(check_for_element);


     });

/* MY OLD CODE WORKS ---> */


var timer = setInterval(function() {

   if (document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized")[1]) {

      /*CODE HERE WORKS UNTIL IT EXISTS NO ERRORS */
     setTimeout (window.close, 5000);


       clearInterval(timer);
   }

}, 200);
```

P.S using opera/ff and tampermonkey/Greasemonkey

Comment: querySelector returns a single element... How are you using it as an array? Doubt your old code worked.

Comment: @paul Hey thanks, that was the problem. Solved it with         var text_area = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='message_']")[1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` returns the *first* matching element, not a list.  If that's what you're looking for, just use:

```
var mine = document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized");

if (mine) {
  // do something with it
}
```

If you really want the *second* element in a list, you want `document.querySelectorAll()`.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("form.compose.initialized");

if (els.length > 1)
{
  var mine = els[1];   

  // do something with it
}
```

Comment: I think this is another question or my lack of under standing of how JS works but I noticed that all my code gets exectued even if request animation is in a loop. 
requestAnimationFrame(check_for_element);
    
    console.log("hey im at the end but I will still get executed even if check_for_element is false. Maybe cause RAF is background browser stuff.");

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine if there is no `form.compose.initialized` then `document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized")` will return `null` and at that time you are trying to access it's 2nd element at index 1, in that case it will be an error.

Instead do,

```
if (document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized")) {
...
}
```

Or

```
if($("form.compose.initialized").length!=0){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` returns an element, not array of elements. Remove `[1]` and it should work.

If you want to check if second element `form.compose.initialized` exists, check length of result:

```
var elements = document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized");
if (elements && elements.length >= 1) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` just returns a single element or `null`, it never returns an array. So there's no reason to index it. It should be

```
if (document.querySelector("form.compose.initialized")) {
    ...
}
```